# GuafretteBundle with Aws SDK2

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, gaufrette

I'm trying to use Gaufrette with Aws SDK2, and I'm getting the following error on a cache:clear after configuring:

```
[Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                          
The provided signature value is not an instance of S3SignatureInterface
```

Here is my setup.

composer.json

```
   "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.6.*@dev"
```

config.yml

```
services:
  src.aws_s3.client:
    class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_method: 'factory'
    arguments:
      key: %amazon_aws_key%
      secret: %amazon_aws_secret_key%
      region: US Standard

...

knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        media_adapter:
            aws_s3:
              service_id: 'src.aws_s3.client'
              bucket_name: my.bucket
              options:
                directory: 'media'
```

GitHub: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/issues/90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a mistake in the arguments of the service declaration (which I should've seen). It needs to be a collection like so:

config.yml

```
services:
  src.aws_s3.client:
    class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_method: 'factory'
    arguments:
      - key: %amazon_aws_key%
        secret: %amazon_aws_secret_key%
```